# How to unzip from PostBuildScript in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event

I'm trying to unzip a File in my PostBuild Event from Visual Studio, but I get an error (Command 'unzip' ended with Code 50) evertime the command gets executed.

```
unzip -o "SourceFile.zip" -d "DestinationFolder"
```

If I run this command from a cmd it works fine.

I googled a bit and found out that Code 50 means either Disk full or insufficient rights.
But my harddrive has plenty of free space. Also I tried runing VS with Admin rights, but still Code 50.

So? Whats wrong with unzip?

Thx

Comment: Do you really use `"DestinationFolder"` and not for example `$(TargetDir)`?

Comment: Yes, I really use DestinationFolder. I can't use $(TargetDir) because that would be a different folder :)

Comment: @Marcel: I meant, do yo use pre/post-build macros or just some pathes. If I understood correctly, just pathes. Right?

Comment: Have you tried specify full path to unzip.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a rar-File out of that zip and use unrar from the winrarfolder and everything works  fine now. (But I'm still interested in the real answer.)

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem. It was caused by the fact that my destination folder string ended with an "\". If I remove this final backslash from the name of the destination folder it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

> powershell Expand-Archive "sourcepath" -DestinationPath "targetpath"

Ex: `powershell Expand-Archive "$(SolutionDir)SomeFolder\Test.zip" -DestinationPath "$(SolutionDir)SomeFolder"`

Comment: This worked for me. I just had to put single quotes around the paths:
powershell Expand-Archive '$(SolutionDir)SomeFolder\Test.zip' -DestinationPath '$(SolutionDir)SomeFolder'

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me:

powershell Expand-Archive '$(SolutionDir)..\x.zip' -DestinationPath '$(SolutionDir)..\'

Answer (score 0):

Escape all pathes with quotes to allow spaces inside, e.g. `"$(TargetDir)"` instead of just `$(TargetDir)`.